# Referring to Nested JSON Data in Vega-Lite

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to reach data in json file but I am getting error : "[Error] Unrecognized signal name: "P"".
I tried to use fold and flatten functions but can't overcome this error. It looks like flatten field is not recognized.

Any ideas why this might happen?

Here is my code:

```
`{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "params": [
    {
      "name": "chart_title",
      "value": " Weekly A Distribution"
    },
    {
      "name": "titleAxisXname",
      "value": "Weekly A Minutes "
    },
    {
      "name": "tick_Count_X",
      "value": 7
    }
  ],
  "width": 425,
  "height": 135,
  "padding": 20,
  "title": {
    "text": {
      "expr": "chart_title"
    },
    "fontSize": 16,
    "color": "#56615F",
    "fontWeight": 700,
    "font": "Google Sans",
    "align": "right",
    "dx": 40,
    "dy": -10
  },
  "data": {
    "values":[
      {
  "customer": "Customer",
  "type": "monthly",
  "period": "2022-10",
  "schema": "1.0.0",
  "metrics": {
    "filters": {
      "age": [
        "all",
        "18-39",
        "40-64",
        "65+"
      ],
      "gender": [
        "all",
        "male",
        "female"
      ]
    },
    "partitions": [
      {
        "segment": {
          "age": "*",
          "gender": "*"
        },
        "count": 10000,
        "a": {
          "mean": 135,
          "p10": 10,
          "p25": 60,
          "p50": 130,
          "p75": 198,
          "p90": 255,
          "goal": {
            "value": 150,
            "p": 0.37
          },
          "distribution": {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 300,
            "step": 10,
            "data": [
              0.01,
              0.01,
              0.02,
              0.03,
              0.05,
              0.08,
              0.13,
              0.21,
              0.28,
              0.31,
              0.33,
              0.3,
              0.28,
              0.26,
              0.24,
              0.22,
              0.21,
              0.2,
              0.19,
              0.18,
              0.17,
              0.16,
              0.15,
              0.14,
              0.13,
              0.12,
              0.11,
              0.1,
              0.09,
              0.08
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
   
  }
    }]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.metrics.partitions", "as": "P"},
    {"flatten": ["P"]},
    {"calculate": "P.a.distribution.data", "as": "data"},
    {"flatten": ["data"], "as": ["d"]},
    {"calculate": "d", "as": "y"},
    {"calculate": "P.a.distribution.max/10" ,"as": "x"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "x",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {}
        ]
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 65
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "25th",
              "Percentile"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 130
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "50th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "datum": 200
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "rule",
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": [
              "75th",
              "Percentile"
            ],
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "background": "#eff1ef",
    "axisX": {
      "title": {
        "expr": "titleAxisXname"
      },
      "tickCount": {
        "expr": "tick_Count_X"
      },
      "titlePadding": 20,
      "titleFont": "Google Sans",
      "titleColor": "#56615F",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": 700,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400
    },
    "axisY": {
      "orient": "right",
      "tickCount": 3,
      "format": "%",
      "title": null,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelPadding": 10
    },
    "line": {
      "point": false,
      "interpolate": "cardinal",
      "color": "#006A62"
    },
    "text": {
      "font": "Google Sans",
      "fontSize": 12,
      "color": "#001D33",
      "fontWeight": 700,
      "dx": 15,
      "dy": -105
    },
    "rule": {
      "strokeWidth": 5,
      "strokeDash": [
        0.5,
        16
      ],
      "strokeCap": "round"
    }
  }
}`
```

Please advise what i am doing wrong? How to overcome this error
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing datum from your references.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "params": [
    {"name": "chart_title", "value": " Weekly A Distribution"},
    {"name": "titleAxisXname", "value": "Weekly A Minutes "},
    {"name": "tick_Count_X", "value": 7}
  ],
  "width": 425,
  "height": 135,
  "padding": 20,
  "title": {
    "text": {"expr": "chart_title"},
    "fontSize": 16,
    "color": "#56615F",
    "fontWeight": 700,
    "font": "Google Sans",
    "align": "right",
    "dx": 40,
    "dy": -10
  },
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {
        "customer": "Customer",
        "type": "monthly",
        "period": "2022-10",
        "schema": "1.0.0",
        "metrics": {
          "filters": {
            "age": ["all", "18-39", "40-64", "65+"],
            "gender": ["all", "male", "female"]
          },
          "partitions": [
            {
              "segment": {"age": "*", "gender": "*"},
              "count": 10000,
              "a": {
                "mean": 135,
                "p10": 10,
                "p25": 60,
                "p50": 130,
                "p75": 198,
                "p90": 255,
                "goal": {"value": 150, "p": 0.37},
                "distribution": {
                  "min": 0,
                  "max": 300,
                  "step": 10,
                  "data": [
                    0.01,
                    0.01,
                    0.02,
                    0.03,
                    0.05,
                    0.08,
                    0.13,
                    0.21,
                    0.28,
                    0.31,
                    0.33,
                    0.3,
                    0.28,
                    0.26,
                    0.24,
                    0.22,
                    0.21,
                    0.2,
                    0.19,
                    0.18,
                    0.17,
                    0.16,
                    0.15,
                    0.14,
                    0.13,
                    0.12,
                    0.11,
                    0.1,
                    0.09,
                    0.08
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "datum.metrics.partitions", "as": "P"},
    {"flatten": ["P"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.data", "as": "data"},
    {"flatten": ["data"], "as": ["d"]},
    {"calculate": "datum.d", "as": "y"},
    {"calculate": "datum.P.a.distribution.max/10", "as": "x"}
  ],
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "x", "type": "quantitative"},
        "y": {"field": "y", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{}]},
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 65}},
      "layer": [
        {"mark": {"type": "rule"}},
        {"mark": {"type": "text", "text": ["25th", "Percentile"]}}
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 130}},
      "layer": [
        {"mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#594CB8"}},
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": ["50th", "Percentile"],
            "color": "#594CB8"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "encoding": {"x": {"datum": 200}},
      "layer": [
        {"mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#B4539E"}},
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "text": ["75th", "Percentile"],
            "color": "#B4539E"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "config": {
    "background": "#eff1ef",
    "axisX": {
      "title": {"expr": "titleAxisXname"},
      "tickCount": {"expr": "tick_Count_X"},
      "titlePadding": 20,
      "titleFont": "Google Sans",
      "titleColor": "#56615F",
      "titleFontSize": 12,
      "titleFontWeight": 700,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400
    },
    "axisY": {
      "orient": "right",
      "tickCount": 3,
      "format": "%",
      "title": null,
      "labelFontSize": 12,
      "labelColor": "#56615F",
      "labelFontWeight": 400,
      "labelPadding": 10
    },
    "line": {"point": false, "interpolate": "cardinal", "color": "#006A62"},
    "text": {
      "font": "Google Sans",
      "fontSize": 12,
      "color": "#001D33",
      "fontWeight": 700,
      "dx": 15,
      "dy": -105
    },
    "rule": {"strokeWidth": 5, "strokeDash": [0.5, 16], "strokeCap": "round"}
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you , new to vega-lite and struggled on this silly mistake